# Can't enable my smart home test application in googe home

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I have a problem with unlocking the test smart home application on the account mobilus.assistant@gmail.com. Id of my project is: mobilus-d9412. After correct linking account with the oAuth2 service in the google home application, the message appears "could not update the setting. Check internet connection". I use the smart home provider nodejs service to handle the action.

From the account piotrmackus@gmail.com through which tests were carried out there is no such problem - it is possible to correctly unlock the application and get the list of devices in the google home application. The project I used for testing is: zxxz-71eee.

I would like the application to work from the mobilus.assistant account from the mobilus-d9412 project, what is the problem? I will add that I use the same android device with google home for both cases, same WiFi network and Google Home mini device.

Comment: Can you check your account settings for each account: https://myaccount.google.com/data-and-personalization

Comment: In the security tab (https://myaccount.google.com/security) I found differences. In Google applications that have access to the account, there is no DialogFlow (Google Cloud Platform) for mobilus.assistant. I will try to give access and let you know about the result

Comment: after giving the dialogflow permission, there is still a problem

Comment: Smart home actions do not use dialogflow. You should verify account settings are the same and disable and re-enable testing for your action in the actions console.

Comment: It seems to me that the settings on both accounts are similar. The action console is all set the same as well. Turning off the test and turning it back on again did not help. Do you have any ideas yet? thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: the problem arises when two gmail accounts are set up on the phone, and the account settings are not set everywhere in the phone settings as selected in the google home application

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have used the Account Linking from Dialogflow / Assistant Actions to build your [Smart Home project](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/create). This kind of flow is not supported anymore, and you should create a new Smart Home project similar to [starter codelab](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/codelabs/smarthome-washer#0), and implement account linking according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/account-linking). Once you start testing your project, go to Actions on Google Console and enable testing (which is not available for Dialgflow projects).